# Xamarin Forms IOS App fails on Database.Migrate()

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, entity-framework-migrations

Good day,

I have a Xamarin Forms App that is cross platform for Android and IOS. I have developed and tested it on android for a while now and everything runs and works fine, but when I try to run the IOS on an emulator, the app keeps failing on the Database.Migrate line.

Please see below:

```
   private readonly string _databasePath;

        public DataContext()
        {
            Database.Migrate();
        }



        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={Singletons.ApplicationSingleton.Instance.DatabasePath}");
        }
```

The error I am getting is the following:

System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not resolve type with token 010000f8 from typeref (expected class 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute' in assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')'

I have had a look at all the references and all is the same versions and also removed the Database.Migrate line, but then it fails as soon as I try to access data in the database.

Has someone ever experienced this? Any solutions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `Database.Migrate();` with  `Database.EnsureCreated();`in class constructor.

The offcial sample works fine on my side .

Refer to the source code https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/2466943d0fb22f4566e289643890baedddf37478/samples/core/Xamarin/EFGetStarted/Services/BloggingContext.cs#L17 .